# Rails 3.2 : class variable initialization

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an ActiveRecord class Settings in my lib  ( autoload on)

```
class Settings < ActiveRecord::Base  
   cattr_accessor :defaults
   @@defaults = {}.with_indifferent_access
   ...
```

I defined an initializer 'settings.rb' , to setup some defaults

```
Settings.defaults[:admin_email] = 'john.doe@acme.com'
#.....
```

when running the console, I should see the defaults, but it's empty :

```
# expected  Settings.admin_email => 'john.doe@acme.com'
Settings.admin_email => {}
```

If I insert a debugger statement , in settings.rb, then I can stop in, even execute the
 Settings.defaults[:admin_email] = 'john.doe@acme.com' but 
 Settings.admin_email => {}

Then if I run in the console:
    Settings.defaults[:admin_email] = 'john.doe@acme.com'
    Settings.admin_email =>  'john.doe@acme.com'

It seem the initializer code is executed, but the class variable is not kept...  could it be related to Rails 3.2 class variable initialization

Comment: If your Settings are in a module Workshop shouldn't you be calling Workshop::Settings or are you including Workshop somewhere before?

Answer (score 0):

May be it's better to use gems to store settings? smth like https://github.com/railsjedi/rails_config